# Can "edition" be used to mean "the act of editing/changing something"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

As one say *creation* for "the act of creating something", couldn't the word *edition* mean "the act of changing something"? I was under the impression it was the case. But a remark from one of my colleagues, telling me I should use *editing* instead, prompted me to check on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edition). As it turned out, I didn't find the meaning I searched under the definitions. Note that my colleague and I both are not native speakers. So which of us is right?

Comment: I someone used **edition** in this sense, I would think they were translating (badly) from their own language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your colleague is correct.  Though it would make sense for *[edition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/edition)* to mean *editing*, it has come only to mean the result of the editing (e.g. *second edition*) or the format of the finished work (e.g. *leather-bound edition*).

It would be better to use *editing* or *revising*.

Comment: Looking at the etymology, "edit" is a back formation from "editor" (the etymology of which is closer to "publisher"). [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=edition) says that in the 16th century, the word "edition" also meant the act of publishing, but that meaning is now long obsolete.

Comment: @Eldroß: *editing* (*revising*) might work, or *edit* (*revision*) might work, depending on the context.  Maybe if you gave the rest of the sentence you were thinking of putting *edition* in, it would help to show what word to use instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the term "[emendation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emendation)" for this purpose.

For example: "Emendation of the injured text was made to restore sense."

[More examples here](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/emendation).

The advantage of using "emend" in this way is that it is often more value-neutral, where "edit" has a somewhat critical nuance that may be unwanted.

Comment: The disadvantage is that it [isn't a common term](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=emend%2Cedit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  Also, I don't think there's that big of a distinction between *edit* and *emend*.  I would hesitate to say that the advantages are great enough to significantly outweigh the disadvantages.

Comment: I do not believe that "commonness" need be the determinant of which word is best in a particular instance.

Comment: No, but it is *a* determinant.  I'm just saying that I don't think it's that much better than *edit* or *revise*.

Comment: The average English speaker has never heard or read the word "emendation" even once.

Comment: I don't know if it would be relevant to changing a database entry through an HTML form, but I learned something new. That's the reason I like E&LU.